# testing flash[:notice] with capybara and activerecord NameError: undefined local variable or method `flash'

Tags: rspec, capybara, sinatra-activerecord

I am very new to building websites and am currently running into the following problem.

I am using ruby, rspec, sinatra, sinatra-flash, capybara and ActiveRecord to design a website.

I am not using rails currently

I have implemented a user signup/login page whereby if the user does not fill up all the fields on sign-in a flash[:notice] should pop up. When I feature test this myself by using sinatra's rackup, it works perfectly. However, when I run rspec using capybara it raises the error:

```
NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `flash'
```

I cannot figure out why this would be. All my other tests pass.

My feature test code:

```
scenario "not filling a field, raises message 'Please ensure you have filled all the fields'" do
    visit('/')
    click_button("Sign up")
    fill_in 'username', with: 'ChrisL'
    fill_in 'last_name', with: 'Lovell'
    fill_in 'first_name', with: 'Chris'
    fill_in 'email', with: 'chris@chris.com'

    expect(current_path).to eq '/sign-up'
    expect(page).to_not have_content "Welcome, ChrisL"
    expect(flash[:notice]).to eq "Please ensure you have filled all the fields"
  end
```

My controller code(removed other routes):

```
class Chitter < Sinatra::Base
    
enable :sessions
register Sinatra::Flash

get '/sign-up' do
    erb :sign_up
end

post '/signing-up' do
  @new_user = User.create(
    username: params[:username], 
    email: params[:email],
    first_name: params[:first_name],
    last_name: params[:last_name],
    password: params[:password]
  )
  @new_user.save
        
  if User.find_by_id(@new_user.id)
    session[:user_id] = @new_user.id
    redirect '/'
  else 
    flash[:notice] = 'Please ensure you have filled all the fields'
    redirect '/sign-up'
  end
end
end
```

My erb file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Chitter Sign In/ Sign Up </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>Chitter: <small>Sign In</small></h1>
    </header>
    <h2 style="color:blue">
      <%= flash[:notice] %>
    </h2>
    <form action="/logging-in" method="post">
      <label for="username">
        Enter Username
        <input type="text" name="log_in_username">
      </label>
      <label for="password">
        Enter A Password 
        <input type="password" name="log_in_password">
      </label>
      <input type="submit" value="Log in">
    </form>
      <br>
    <header>
      <h1>Chitter: <small>Sign Up</small></h1>
    </header>
    <h3> Sign Up For The Unique Experience </h3>
    <form action="/signing-up" method="post">
      <label for="username">
        Enter Desired Username
        <input type="text" name="username">
      </label>
      <br>
      <label for="first_name">
        Enter Your First Name
        <input type="text" name="first_name">
      </label>
      <br>
      <label for="last_name">
        Enter Your Last Name 
        <input type="text" name="last_name">
      </label>
      <br>
      <label for="email">
        Enter Your Email 
        <input type="text" name="email">
      </label>
      <br>
        <label for="password">
        Enter A Password 
        <input type="password" name="password">
      </label>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Sign up">
    </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

While `flash` is valid inside your controller, Capybara deals with what is on the page, which is what you should be checking, so `flash` has no meaning. In your erb you are putting the flash notice inside an h2 so the test for that would be

```
expect(page).to have_css('h2', text: "Please ensure you have filled all the fields")
```

Going forward you might want to add an id to the container (h2) of the flash messages so you can more excatly target it.

Comment: I attempted to do that but am now getting the following error message: 1) signing up not filling a field, raises message 'Please ensure you have filled all the fields'
     Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_css('h2', text: "Please ensure you have filled all the fields")
       expected to find visible css "h2" with text "Please ensure you have filled all the fields" but there were no matches. Also found "", which matched the selector but not all filters.

Comment: I have also tried expect(page).to have_content "Please ensure you have filled all the fields" but it doesn't display as content either

Comment: @Chris Then the text isn't on the page. Check that you're doing the actions you think you are - for instance, you're not clicking anything to submit the form after filling in the fields which may be necessary to trigger the post to /signing-up which would be required for the flash to be rendered. Additionally you should "never" be using RSpecs basic matchers(eq, etc) with Capybara things, but instead use the Capybara matchers which have waiting/retrying behavior built-in. So rather than `expect(current_path).to eq '/sign-up'` you should be using `expect(page).to have_current_path('/sign_up')`